# Why xpath changes the HTML?

Tags: php, xpath

Here is my code: [Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/JgL5R)

```
$html_string = <<<STR
<p>paragraph<a>link</a></p>
<div class="myclass">
    <div>something</div>
    <div style="mystyle">something</div>
    <b><a href="#">link</a></b>
    <b><a href="#" name="a name">link</a></b>
    <b style="color:red">bold</b>
    <img src="../path" alt="something" />
    <img src="../path" alt="something" class="myclass" />
</div>
STR;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html_string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//@*');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {             
    if($node->nodeName != "src" && $node->nodeName != "href" && $node->nodeName != "alt") {
        $node->parentNode->removeAttribute($node->nodeName);
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

As you see in the demo, the place of `</p>` isn't right in the output. I mean the position of it has been changed. Why? And how can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every DOMDocument needs a root node. For HTML documents, it is usually the `<html>` node.

Because root node is **mandatory**, in your case **libXML took the first node**, your `p` element, **as the root node**.
That's why the next node `div[@class="myclass"]` became a child of your `p` element with `$dom->saveHTML();`

Wrap your code in a root node like `<html>` to solve your problem

```
$html_string = <<<STR
<html>
<p>paragraph<a>link</a></p>
<div class="myclass">
    <div>something</div>
    <div style="mystyle">something</div>
    <b><a href="#">link</a></b>
    <b><a href="#" name="a name">link</a></b>
    <b style="color:red">bold</b>
    <img src="../path" alt="something" />
    <img src="../path" alt="something" class="myclass" />
</div>
</html>
STR;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html_string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//@*');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {             
    if($node->nodeName != "src" && $node->nodeName != "href" && $node->nodeName != "alt") {
        $node->parentNode->removeAttribute($node->nodeName);
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: yes it works, thank you, upvote ..! just can you please tell me why do I need `<html>` tag surround it?

Comment: Im glad my answer is useful. I just edited it to give you the reason behind. In few words : a **root node** is mandatory with DOMDocument.